# Getting lowercase letters in serialized data

Tags: c#, json, botframework

I am trying to send some data to an API by serialising it. But after JSONSerialization all the keys were become lowercase letters. SO that API is returning the result as bad request. Why it is happening ? I have applied Json Property to each field......still it's not working.

```
public class ShoppingCartDTO
    {
        [JsonProperty("Userid")]
        public string Userid { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Msgv1")]
        public string Msgv1 { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Data")]
        public string Data{ get; set; }
   }
```

before calling the API, I have serialized it like this:

```
  using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = container }))
            {
                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dto);
}
```

Comment: Your code is working normally on my end http://take.ms/u8VuGb

Comment: Small side note, it's just converting the first letter to lower case. `UserId` would have become `userId`

Comment: But I am getting it as useid, is any problem with making the data model class as serializable ?

Answer (score 4):

If you have case-sensitive clients that cannot be easily updated, change your Startup from

```
  services.AddMvc();
```

to

```
  services
    .AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());
```

see more in 
https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4842